# Stashing Entry Ids not working with get tag

Tags: templates, stash

I've got a stash set like this:

```
{!-- retrieved at line 173--}
{exp:stash:set name="st_featured_ids" type="snippet" parse_tags="yes"}
    {director_featured_spots backspace="1"}{director_featured_spots:entry_id}|{/director_featured_spots}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

And in a test section of the template outputs entry ids as expected using this:

```
stashed: {exp:stash:get name='st_featured_ids'  type='snippet'}
```

However when I'm trying to filter a relationship tag to only show specific entries it doesn't work. If I manually add in the entry_ids it's fine. I jsut cant' get them with stash.

```
{parents field="spot_director" limit="5" entry_id="{exp:stash:get name='st_featured_ids'  type='snippet'}"};

or

{parents field="spot_director" limit="5" entry_id="{st_featured_ids}"}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try adding ye oldē ` parse="inward"` tag on the relationship tag

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try `{exp:stash:st_featured_ids}`? I have run into this issue before but will need to review my code to see how I dealt with it (it's been a while since I encountered it).

Comment: Robert, yes. Getting some help from Mark Croxton on devot:ee but haven't resolved it yet